# How to implement List.Remove against two different object list?

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists : `ListA<A>` and `ListB<B>`

Structure of object:
Object A : - commonID , AName
Object B : - commonID , BName

Now my objective is very simple, I'm trying to remove all items in `ListA` that having the same `commonID` as in `ListB`. Below is what I've tried:

```
foreach(var item in ListB)
    ListA.Remove(x=>x.commonID == item.commonID)
```

It's throwing exception:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'A' because it is not a delegate type
```

May I know which part am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently using [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which takes an individual item to remove) instead of [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which takes a predicate).

However, a better approach might be to create a set of all IDs you want to remove, and then use a single call to `RemoveAll`:

```
HashSet<string> idsToRemove = new HashSet<string>(ListB.Select(x => x.commonID));
ListA.RemoveAll(x => idsToRemove.Contains(x.commonID));
```

Or if your lists are small enough that you're not worried about it being an O(N*M) operation, you can use:

```
ListA.RemoveAll(x => ListB.Any(y => x.commonID == y.commonID));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Remove method does not take a predicate, but an actual item. So your error message means that your lambda expression cannot be converted to the expected item of type A.

[RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a predicate:

```
ListA.RemoveAll(item => ListB.Any(x => x.CommonId == item.CommonID));
```

Now you don't even need the outer loop.

Comment: Contains doesn't take delegate as parameter

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you are right, I changed it to Any.